# Android Lollipop - ripple effect in notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable

I want to add ripple effect to the ImageView / ImageButton in notification on Android Lollipop. I saw that this is possible on Google Play Music. However solution that I was using with other views does not work with notifications.

I've created RippleDrawable in drawable-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="#33000000">
</ripple>
```

And set this drawable as background of ImageView

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/notification_play_button"
           tools:src="@drawable/av_play_over_video"
           android:layout_width="32dp"
           android:layout_height="32dp"
           android:background="@drawable/button_selector_semi_black"
            />
```

But it simply does not work. Do you have any ideas how to achieve this effect?

Comment: I suspect that you want a `<selector>` (`StateListDrawable`) that applies the ripple when the button is clicked.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was trying to add `<selector>` with  `<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_selector_semi_black">` where `button_selector_semi_black` is my ripple with no effect :( maybe is too late and I am blind :/

Comment: If you are testing on the emulator, AFAIK you would need Host GPU mode on to see the effect. I can't use Host GPU mode on my Ubuntu setup (though I haven't tried it recently, so maybe they fixed the bug), but to see ripples I have to test on Android 5.0 hardware.

Comment: I am testing on Genymotion with Android 5.0.0 and HTC One GPE with 5.0.1 ;/

Comment: Same in Marshmallow. Have you raised a bug report in the issue tracker?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you used "RemoteViews" to customized your notification layout.

Try to add **"android:background="@android:color/transparent"**

in your customized layout's view group.

Comment: With this, the ripple works BUT I found a very ugly bug in some Samsung phones (like S6). If you use this, the notification will be actually transparent (yes you can see the stuff behind it). It might be a bug only with Samsung but it is still annoying... Without setting a background at all works everywhere but then the ripple for buttons is not visible.

Comment: This doesn't make ripple effect work in RemoteViews.